# SOQL join query based on a custom child traversing up to a standard parent

Tags: join, parent-child, soql

I have a custom object `Projet__c`, child of `Account`, that I need to make a query on e.g. `SELECT Id FROM Projet__c LIMIT 10`. This works.

I want to retrieve the Account Name.

If the child was not custom, for example `Contact`, I could simply run
`SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Contact` (this works).

However `SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Projet__c` fails with the following error message :

> INVALID_FIELD: 
>   SELECT Name, Account.Name
>              ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:14
>   Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Looking in Workbench, I can see that in Account, there is a child relationship `projets__r` with a custom field called `BorrowerBusiness__c` which is equal to `Account.Id`. Running the query on `FROM projets__r` or similar variants fail.

I could run the query the other way, `SELECT Name, (SELECT Id from projets__r) FROM Account`, which works but also returns all accounts without a project and is extremely slow as a result. This also precludes doing two queries and merging in e.g. Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

After trying dozens of combinations, what seems to work is `SELECT BorrowerBusiness__r.Name FROM Projet__c`. I have no idea why but hey...